# VSTS Git Object Count much larger than expected

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm a relative newbie to GIT and Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS, cloud based free version of Team Foundation Server)  and I've just recently started using it for our website development.

I'm concerned at the time it takes when creating a release, checking out the files takes quite a few minutes, I'm guessing due to the large number of objects its trying to process? The object count states 23,909 ?   I've done a TreeSize on the repository (excl .git folder) and it shows the following?

also tried `git gc --aggressive --prune` but this didnt reduce the file count.

Its possible that there was a large folder of images stored in the repository but I'm pretty certain they were removed, as they dont show in the git or on the VSTS website?

Glad of any help!

[image]
[image]

For those interested, here is a log from the last release I did.

https://codeshare.io/5w0qop

Comment: Are you putting binaries into your Git repo? If you are, that's a big problem.

Comment: Yeah i am, what's the alternative?

Comment: By using a `.gitignore` file to exclude binaries.

Comment: Then how do I build and release without binaries?

Comment: Your build should generate binaries and publish them as artifacts (using the `Publish Artifacts` task). Then your release can grab the artifacts from your build output.

Comment: It's an ASP app so It has dependancies

Comment: That doesn't change anything; your build process should be responsible for compiling your application, bundling it up in a deployable package, and publishing it as an artifact. Your release process can then consume and deploy that artifact however you'd like. Source control is not the correct place to store binary outputs or packages. Packages can be restored at build time via NuGet package restore.

Comment: Ok, where do I put the binaries if they arent available on NuGet or publiclly available for download?

Comment: You turn them into NuGet packages and host them in a package management feed in VSTS.

Comment: Ok thanks will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

There is perhaps nothing to be afraid of because git objects are used to store all the history for files, trees and commits objects.

You could have a look to [git sizer](https://github.com/github/git-sizer) to get a better view/count of the objects stored. And it could give you hints of why your repository is big (in size or number of files).

If you will have to clean your history (but first really understand what it means!), you could have a look to [BFG repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) which is a very good tool...

Also I'm not sure that your local object count is representative to the one of the repository (except if you did a fresh clone).

You surely have a lot of objects that you created just locally.

> also tried git gc --aggressive --prune but this didnt reduce the file count.

There is also a good reason why it don't reduce the size. That's because a lot of objects are retained by the reflog (a log book that permit to repair mistakes!).

So if you really want to purge useless objects, you need to clean the reflog first with:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
```

> I'm concerned at the time it takes when creating a release, checking out the files takes quite a few minutes, I'm guessing due to the large number of objects its trying to process?

VSTS build every time on a new VM, so it should clone the entire repository each time :( instead of just fetching the differences.

If you don't need the entire history (which is most of the time the case except if you compute version based on the git history), you perhaps should do a shallow clone by setting the `depth` to 1 in the VSTS git repository settings of your build. It will fetch less objects.

PS: what do you want to show exactly with TreeSize? Just that you only have 3415 files?